# Save and load random image to isolated storage

Tags: image, windows-phone-7, isolatedstorage

I  added some pictures (png ) to my project and i load a random image at a stackpanel .  I wanto to save that image to isolated storage and load it from it but how i can save a random image ???

Answer (score 0):

Use this code to save Image byte stream to IS:

```
            using (IsolatedStorageFileStream fileStream = new IsolatedStorageFileStream(tempJPEG, FileMode.Create, myIsolatedStorage))
            {
                using (BinaryWriter writer = new BinaryWriter(fileStream))
                {
                    Stream resourceStream = new MemoryStream(imageData); //Byte[] imageData
                    long length = resourceStream.Length;
                    byte[] buffer = new byte[32];
                    int readCount = 0;

                    using (resourceStream)
                    {   
                        resourceStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);

                        // Read file in chunks in order to reduce memory consumption and increase performance
                        while (readCount < length)
                        {
                            int actual = resourceStream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
                            readCount += actual;
                            writer.Write(buffer, 0, actual);
                        }
                    }
                }

                fileStream.Close();
            }
```